# Solve the recurrence relation $a_{n+1} = 10a_n+n+1$, $\forall n\ge0$ with $a_0= 0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve this recurrence relation. I'm currently in discrete with graph theory and have not taken linear algebra / differential equations so I don't have the largest toolbox for solving these type of problems.

I understand that $p(n)$ can be any particular solution to the relation, and $q(n)$ can be the general solution, therefore $a_n = p(n) + q(n)$

So if I take $p_n = a + bn$

can I just directly plug that into the initial equation getting:

$a(n+1) + b = 10(an + b) + n + 1$ ?

or am I completely missing the mark here?

If there is a youtube video, or some other video that you would recommend I would be extremely grateful. I would really like to understand this better.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math. Your question will be better received in this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation as $$a_{n+1}-10a_n=n+1\tag1$$
This is an inhomogeneous linear difference equation.  ("Inhomogeneous" because the right-hand side is not $0$).  The corresponding homogeneous equation is $$a_{n+1}-10a_n=0\tag2$$  The theorem you are thinking of is that the general solution to $(1)$ is the general solution to $(2)$ plus any particular solution to $(1)$.

The general solution to $(2)$ is $$a_n=10^nk$$ for some constant $k$.  To find the a particular solution of $(1)$, because the right hand side is a linear polynomial, we guess that there will be a particular solution that is also of this form: $a_n=cn+d.$  Substituting into $(1)$ gives $$
c(n+1)+d = 10(cn+d)+n+1\\
cn+c+d=10cn+10d+n+1\\
c-1-9d=(9c+1)n$$
To eliminate the $n$, we take $c=-\frac19$.  Then $d=-\frac{10}{81}$ giving $$a_n=-\frac{9n+10}{81}$$ as a particular solution to $(1)$.  (You should check this.)

Now the general solution to $(1)$ is $$a_n=10^nk-\frac{9n+10}{81}$$ and we have only to determine $k$ by substituting $a_0=0$. I'll leave that part for you.

Comment: Thank you, so much! I'm taking this class remotely and have been searching for some explanation like this for a few days now. I can't tell you how grateful I am for this. 

I have to go to work, but I will put my work up for k when I get off.

Comment: @Purpleskittles My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$a_1=1$$

$$a_2=10×1+2$$

$$a_3=10(10×1+2)+2+1=10^2+2×10+3$$

$$a_4=10(10^2+2×10+3)+3+1=10^3+2×10^2+3×10+4$$

$$a_5=10(10^3+2×10^2+3×10+4)+4+1=10^4+2×10^3+3×10^2+4×10+5$$

Finally,  by induction we have:

$$\begin{align}\color {gold}{\boxed {\color{black}{a_0=0, ~a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k10^{n-k}}}}\end{align}$$

---

It is possible to prove that

$$\begin{align}\color {gold}{\boxed {\color{black}{a_0=0,~ a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k10^{n-k}=\frac{1}{81} (10^{n+1} - 9n-10).}}}\end{align}$$

Comment: That is the generating function that you used right? I am working with a text book that has  a 4 page section on solving recurrence relations with the characteristic polynomial and that's it. 

But if I kinda understand the way the generating function works is you get the first couple terms in the sequence and that allows you to get your lower bound of 1 and upper bound n. And that is about where I fall off in understanding.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

This problem was here some days ago. I will write the same hint I wrote before.

$$a_{n+1} = 10a_n+n+1$$
$$a_{n} = 10a_{n-1}+(n-1)+1$$

Now, subtract both equations,

$$a_{n+1}-a_n = 10(a_n-a_{n-1})+1$$

Can you finish?

Comment: I know, I saw your hint and was going to try and respond before. I know that to use n in this you need to replace it with (n-1). But I get lost when 10−1+(−1)+1, goes to +1−=10(−−1)+1. 

How is the (n-1) replaced with (−−1).

Comment: @Purpleskittles, I am subtracting both equations. Take the equation of $a_{n+1}$ and subtract from the equation of $a_n$. Another way to see this is isolate $n$ in both equations and equalize them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple trick to solve this problem easily: Note that given sequence is "roughly" a GP (apparent from the given recursive step). So let's do a translation to make it a GP exactly. Define $b_n = a_n+kn+l$. Now the recursion becomes
\begin{align}
&b_{n+1}-k(n+1)-l = 10b_n-10kn-10l+n+1\\
\implies&b_{n+1}=10b_n+n(-9k+1)+k+1-9l
\end{align}
Solving for the coefficient of $n$ and constant term to be zero, we get $k=\frac19$ and $l=\frac{10}{81}$. Now apply the general formula for the GP get $b_n$ and hence get $a_n$.